# Parse one string column in dataframe column into many other columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column in a pandas data frame that contains string like the following format as for example

```
fullyRandom=true+mapSizeDividedBy64=51048
mapSizeDividedBy16000=9756+fullyRandom=false
qType=MpmcArrayQueue+qCapacity=822398+burstSize=664
count=11087+mySeed=2+maxLength=9490
capacity=27281
capacity=79882
```

we can read for example the first row as 2 parameters separated by '+' each parameter has a value, that clear by '=' that separate between the parameter and its value.

in Output, I'm asking if there is a python script that either extract the parameters we retrieve a list of unique parameters  like the following

```
[fullyRandom,mapSizeDividedBy64,mapSizeDividedBy64,qType,qCapacity,qCapacity, count,mySeed,maxLength,Capacity]
```

Notice from the previous list that it contains only the unique parameters without its values

Or extended pandas data frame if it's not too difficult if we can parse the following column and convert into many columns, each column is for one parameter  that store it's value in it

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: either a list of unique parameters (the one on the left of = operator) per in mind that there could be more than one parameters in one row separated by +  
OR if it's not so difficult we could transfer this column into many columns one per each parameter, each new columns contains the corresponding values, in the posted example there sould be 10 coulmns @yatu

Comment: What do you mean by columns? Are you working with pandas? Please share a more complete example and the expected output

Comment: Yes I'm working with pandas datafram @yatu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it will store the values in a list.

```
data = []
with open('<your text file>', 'r') as file:
    content = file.readlines()

    for row in content:
        if '+' in row:
            sub_row = row.strip('\n').split('+')
                for r in sub_row:
                    data.append(r)
        else:
            data.append(row.strip('\n'))

print(data)
```

Output:

```
['fullyRandom=true', 'mapSizeDividedBy64=51048', 'mapSizeDividedBy16000=9756', 'fullyRandom=false', 'qType=MpmcArrayQueue', 'qCapacity=822398', 'burstSize=664', 'count=11087', 'mySeed=2', 'maxLength=9490', 'capacity=27281', 'capacity=79882']
```

to convert to a list of dict that could be used in pandas:

```
dict_list = []
for item in data:
    df = {
        item.split('=')[0]: item.split('=')[1]
    }
    dict_list.append(df)
print(dict_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'fullyRandom': 'true'}, {'mapSizeDividedBy64': '51048'}, {'mapSizeDividedBy16000': '9756'}, {'fullyRandom': 'false'}, {'qType': 'MpmcArrayQueue'}, {'qCapacity': '822398'}, {'burstSize': '664'}, {'count': '11087'}, {'mySeed': '2'}, {'maxLength': '9490'}, {'capacity': '27281'}, {'capacity': '79882'}]
```

To just get the headers:

```
dict_list.append(item.split('=')[0])
```

Output:

```
['fullyRandom', 'mapSizeDividedBy64', 'mapSizeDividedBy16000', 'fullyRandom', 'qType', 'qCapacity', 'burstSize', 'count', 'mySeed', 'maxLength', 'capacity', 'capacity']
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but for me I want a unique list of parameters without its value @Zuks Maq

Comment: @Peter, Ive just updated the answer. Hope this helps but Im sure theres a much more complicated way to do this :)

Comment: thanks really a lot, but for me, I need only the unique values (fully random should be one time in the list), because in the original data I have 5 millions of rows which really costly we take all the parameters even repeated @Zuks Maq

Comment: @Peter you can covert to a Set, that will give you the unique values.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot @Zuks Maq